# New Ubuntu 20.04 installation stuck after login

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, 20.04

I tried searching but couldn't find anything to solve this issue.

I tried several times to install Ubuntu 20.04 using the "Ubuntu" option, but it always was getting stuck in the filesystem check at 0% in the beginning of the installation. Trying to hit Ctrl+c did nothing.

I could finally install it using the option "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" option. BUT, after installation, it took a long time to start, around 5 - 10 minutes - It was installed in a SSD drive. The login screen finally was presented, but after typing my user and password, the UI is stuck. It's only a purple screen with the mouse pointer.

[Snapshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRycS.jpg)

Tried several times and the result is always the same: a long time to start and the mouse in a purple screen.
Tried reinstalling it and the same issue happens.

Anyone knows what may be happening?

My laptop is a Dell Inpiron 15 gaming with core I7, 16 GB RAM and nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 19.04 and this was the reason to give up using Ubuntu in the past. I just couldn't find a solution for that.

Thank you very much in advance!